# How to decode CSR string in python?

Tags: python, ssl, csr

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIICvDCCAaQCAQAwdzELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEjAQBgNVBAgTCVlvdXJTdGF0ZTER
MA8GA1UEBxMIWW91ckNpdHkxCzAJBgNVBAsTAklUMRowGAYDVQQKExFZb3VyQ29t
cGFueSwgSW5jLjEYMBYGA1UEAxMPd3d3LmV4YW1wbGUuY29tMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG
9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA379BFFxfACdXsUk2wrQka/nAlKbo+I9DAW32
+/SRxj/KtXVddscKW1obHGpMKPw4meJqOpQwJkIChYjSUQSpPKzdGpccDMf/eoF0
J7EaQ2szLv9AqdRQw2Aaek8SmocVmd3LxEOX4VvALBOMLHVrB5/vhYfGECLJbc3l
RdEbdXyHDtHklRAoIVQCfjTwBWGNAD337vmHW7Q0R6FYUoa4fcJh7Rv6jHSywqwx
7pVfaDbZPuTgUhw7wksKNFxccG0xcTMr/+GrciHEuZ0chq86CBP9RIyLpp2+RMSf
m6rMEYm9o65j7vEYaKEJUOJtA5MIs/ZjaXfS1LjXurLU0nCOQQIDAQABoAAwDQYJ
KoZIhvcNAQEFBQADggEBAK159goyAYOpcnrQ2EvCGlizrK1kS3D8JjnAiP1NHrjB
/qdTYR+/8Dr/hMcwwU5ThGAVf68eMkk6tUNwAdpZ9C904Js2z+ENEbO8GA0Fc4rw
ix7vb15vSXe3shGijRGIzzHVGRoR3r7xQtIuMaDAr3xlV8jHbcvZTcpX0Kbq6H1G
NLA4CXsOI4KGwu4FXfSzJEGb3gEJD8HaMP8V8er5G0owv/g/9Z/1/b0g97kAcUwk
M2eDsvPhMx/pENGbnLPe4XMy7NPiEdzFnaYtUy2BDcXj3ZQEWxRWklERgg9/YcWI
obf5ziuNm1Df24NBt5tpCNzfGviKT6/RYfWg3dMaKxc=
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

I need signature algorithm data from it but I don't know how i achieve it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
from cryptography.x509 import load_pem_x509_csr

req = load_pem_x509_csr(b'''
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIICvDCCAaQCAQAwdzELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEjAQBgNVBAgTCVlvdXJTdGF0ZTER
...
obf5ziuNm1Df24NBt5tpCNzfGviKT6/RYfWg3dMaKxc=
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
''');

print(req.signature_hash_algorithm.name)
```